# Bluetooth pairing dialog not shown in lock task mode

Tags: android, bluetooth, popup, pairing, android-screen-pinning

I am writing an Android Lock Task Mode application. Everything works fine except when I need to give the users access to a few settings like mobile roaming and Bluetooth printer pairing.

When I make these settings available by adding the relevant packages in the call to `setLockTaskPackages` like this:

`mDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(mAdminComponentName, new String[]{getPackageName(),  Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS, Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS});`

then when they try to launch the Bluetooth configuration, the pairing dialog does not show up, probably because lock task mode is preventing the popup.

I can get the popup to show up by adding the complete settings (`"com.android.settings"`) package to the list but that defeats the purpose of the lock task mode as users are able to access all the settings we didn't want to give them access to in the first place.

Is there a way to bring up the pairing dialog without opening up the complete settings?

Also is there a way to enable access to mobile roaming in lock task mode?

This would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: This topic is not too hot here, although I have seen it asked many times. Never a satisfactory answer. Is this a hole in Google Android's strategy?

I could not even find a place at Google where I could pay for support. It is not acceptable that enterprises developing solutions spend days searching the NET to find answers. There must be a way to get that support. Perhaps I am missing something in Google's Android business model. If someone knows please enlighten me! SMH